# Java Lists: Difference between assignment while instantiating and after

Tags: java, list, arraylist, instantiation, difference

This error only occurs when I assign values to an arrayList after it has been Instantiated. 
[This is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsto6.png)

This only occurs when the code is like this:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
line = line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " ");
line = line.toLowerCase();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
words.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words.toArray()));
```

The program works fine when the code is like this:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
line = line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " ");
line = line.toLowerCase();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
words.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words.toArray()));
```

Thanks for any type of further explanation and advice :)

Comment: Post the error stack trace in the question, as text. Not as a link to an image. And read the javadoc of Arrays.asList(). Creating a new ArrayList and assigning it to words, to replace it by a different list just the line after is wasteful. That's basically like filling a bottle with milk, then flushing it in the toilets to fill it with water after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This error only occurs when I assign values to an arrayList after it has been Instantiated.

That's not what you are doing here:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
```

You are assigning an empty `ArrayList` to `words`, and then you assign a different `List`, created by `Arrays.asList(line.split(" "))`, to `words`. That second `List` is a fixed sized `List`, so you can't remove elements from it.

There's no point to initialize `words` to an empty `ArrayList`, if later you assign a different `List` to it.

If you want to use the `ArrayList` you initialized the `words` variable with, use `addAll` for the second statement:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
```

The problem is this line - Arrays.asList() creates an **immutable** list, which you can't add / remove items afterwards

Comment: Nope, Arrays.asList() doesn't create an immutable list. It creates a fixed-size mutable list backed by the array.